# Android webView - links with attribute download not working

Tags: android, webview

I noticed that links with the attribute "download" are not working.

```
<a href="/media/wysiwyg/pdf/systemaufbau-anleitungen.pdf" target="_blank" download="blizz-z_Systemaufbau_Anleitungen">
```

So I tried to inject some javascript to remove it, but it does not work:

```
    // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        // Notify the host application that a page has finished loading.
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

             // Hide/Show back button
            backButton = findViewById(R.id.backButton);
            backButton.setEnabled(blizzView.canGoBack());

            if (blizzView.canGoBack()) {
                backButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                backButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            blizzView.loadUrl(
                    "javascript:(function() {" +
                            "setInterval(function() {" +
                                "jQuery('a').each(function() {"
                                    + "jQuery(this).removeAttr('download');"
                                    + "jQuery('#myInput').css('background', '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16));"
                                + "});"
                            + "}, 1000);"
                    + "});"
            );
```

I am giving the searchbar of my site a random color every second to confirm that the script runs, but it does not change the color... 
I tested the script on my [website](https://www.blizz-z.de) in the developer console and it runs, but it does not run from the app.

Answer (score 0):

I had to write a workaround since this must be a bug in Android webView.
I just run through each `a` tag and strip the `download` attribute, now it works.

**Code:**

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    website = "https://www.blizz-z.de";
    myWebView = findViewById(R.id.blizzView);

    WebSettings settings = blizzView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        // Notify the host application that a page has finished loading.
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            js(myWebView, "jQuery(document).ready(function() {" +
                        "setInterval(function() {" +
                            + "jQuery('#myInput').css('background', '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16));"
                        + "}, 1000);"
                    + "});"
            );
        }
    }

    ...

}

public void js(WebView view, String code)
{
    String javascriptCode = "javascript:" + code;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        view.evaluateJavascript(javascriptCode, new ValueCallback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String response) {
                Log.i("debug_log", response);
            }
        });
    } else {
        view.loadUrl(javascriptCode);
    }
}
```

I created an [Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138239204).